# How can I create a DynamicProxy for a WCF proxy that is generated by ChannelFactory<T>?

Tags: .net-4.0, castle-dynamicproxy

I am using ChannelFactory to create a proxy at run-time for a WCF service. I would like to use the DynamicProxy Castle project to create a dynamic proxy on top of the WCF proxy so that I can intercept calls and do impersonation.

I'm getting an error when I try this though... the error message is:

> 'this' type cannot be an interface itself.

My code is this (where T is a service contract interface):

```
var generator = new ProxyGenerator();

return (T)generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(T), channel, 
    new[] { new ImpersonationInterceptor() } );
```

The problem must have to do with the fact that the service proxy generated by ChannelFactory is generated at runtime, but is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is - use WCF Facility, it is replacing WCF proxy with Castle's DynamicProxy.

The problem here, is that you're trying to build a proxy on top of a proxy, and remoting proxies have some... specific behaviors, result of which is the error you're getting.

Comment: This doesn't appear to help with my issue. Am I missing something? This looks like it's for the service side, not the client side.

Comment: can you show an example showing a solution to the original problem?